# Can't reach server inside docker container from host

Tags: macos, docker, go

I am hosting a `mysql` server and a `go` http server in docker. I am unable to hit the http server from my host machine. My host machine is a mac.

I have tried using `localhost:8080` and `ipofserver:8080`. I get the `ip` from the `docker inspect`. I am able to connect to my `mysql` server from my host, but i can't hit the server from the host.

Here is my `docker ps` output.

```
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Below are my details:

Docker Desktop version 2.0.0.3.

docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        networks:
            - mynetwork

    server:
        image: server:latest
        networks:
             - mynetwork
        ports:
             - "8080:8080"

volumes:
    mysql: ~

networks:
    mynetwork:
        driver: "bridge"
```

mysql dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0.16

COPY ./scripts/mysql/dbgen-v1.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

server dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.12.5

WORKDIR a/go/path
COPY . .

ENV GOBIN=/usr/local/bin

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go get github.com/iancoleman/strcase
RUN go get github.com/jmoiron/sqlx
RUN go get github.com/spf13/cobra
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/websocket
RUN go get github.com/spf13/viper

RUN go install -v cmd/project/main.go

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["main"]
```

Comment: I have two wild guesses: 1) you use a custom bridge network and port publishing only works for the default one--you can try removing the custom network config and also "unwire" the containers from it (then the default bridge network will kick in). I can't test this now but I think https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/ suggests this might be the case.  2) the web server is not responding--you can verify that by checking whether it responds inside the container (e.g. by running something like `docker-compose exec server curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @TomaszZieliński Doing your (2) option worked. Will try 1 now.

Comment: As for (2), the server also needs to bind to 0.0.0.0 and not to 127.0.0.1, otherwise it won't bind to the bridge interface and so it won't be visible outside the container no matter what the network setup is.

Comment: @TomaszZieliński I tried (1) and it did not work. With (1) number (2) is still working.

Comment: Did you recreate the containers or just restart them? In order to apply the new network settings you need to do `docker-compose up` once again.

Comment: @TomaszZieliński I did recreate the containers. What fixed the problem was changing my server address to `0.0.0.0`. Thank you so much! Add this as an answer, and i will accept it.

Comment: @TomaszZieliński Any ideas on why my server can't connect to the mysql server? I get this message when trying to connect: `127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused`

Comment: Mysql doesn't bind to 127.0.0.1 inside the web server container. You should be able to use `http://mysql:3306` as then Docker DNS will resolve `mysql` to the correct IP address of mysql container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(This answer is based on the chat we had in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514763/cant-reach-server-inside-docker-container-from-host#comment99616009_56514763))*

In order to expose the web server from inside the container to the host it needs to bind to 0.0.0.0 and not to 127.0.0.1. Using 0.0.0.0 ensures that the web server binds to the bridge interface that can be accessed from the host side.

Relevant Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: It is still not working. Maybe the bridge network got deleted??